# Can wikipedia links be considered as good references?

Tags: discussion, answer-quality

There was a [question](https://security.stackexchange.com/q/33257/21234) related to attack terms like DNS spoofing and DNS cache poisoning.
Now most times these two terms are used interchangeably. But I wanted a solid reference document to support this but could not find any (mentioned it in a comment).

I saw the Wikipedia article but for some reason I felt that giving a Wikipedia article as a reference in the answers will not be a good thing. Later there was an answer which gave the Wikipedia link.

I wonder is it a good practice to give Wikipedia links in your answers?

Comment: As long as you have an answer in addition to the link, not just the link on its own.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In general, I think it is good practice to give references.

Of course the quality of references varies a lot. Wikipedia is obviously better than some random website. But a website from someone with a high reputation in the security context may be better. Ideally the reference goes to a peer reviewed research paper.

Often Wikipedia articles have a References section at the end.

To summarize: Referencing Wikipedia is okay. If someone comes up with a higher quality reference, even better.

Answer (score 6):

A [Wikipedia](http://www.wikipedia.org/) [link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperlink) should never [stand in place](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Substitution_cipher) for an [answer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Answer). I [find](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discovery_%28observation%29) the best [uses](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Use_case) of it are much like within [Wikipedia](http://www.wikipedia.org/) itself; [words](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Word) within an otherwise complete [answer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Answer) that might [raise questions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Confusion) or be [beyond the scope](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scope_%28computer_science%29) of the [explanation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Explanation) should be [linked](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperlink) to [Wikipedia](http://www.wikipedia.org/) [articles](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Article_%28publishing%29).

With regard to [references](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reference), I believe [Wikipedia](http://www.wikipedia.org/) is a [perfectly](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perfection) [acceptable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Acceptance) [source](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Source_%28journalism%29) to cite<sup>[1.]</sup>.

**Bibliography**

1. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Citation

Comment: Perfect. 2 additions: I would expand that there are times where it is good to quote a section of a WP article, but again in addition to the otherwise complete answer. Also, note that there ARE wikipedia articles which may not be 100% correct, accurate, or complete. In short, unlike [skeptics.se], while WP is not an authoritative source, it is a pretty decent substitute. It is good as prepared explanation, but it cannot stand in place of good analysis and reason.

Comment: @AviD thanks, now I have to spend all afternoon reading Skeptics.